# Where does RGB keyboard animation code run?

Tags: keyboards

I've done some googling and haven't really found anything.

Where does keyboard animation code typically run?

I'm in the market for a new RGB keyboard and I'd like one that can do a color-complement ripple effect like my current Roccat Vulcan 100 AIMO, but not by running node.js on my PC (which is how it works now), which makes it pretty laggy.

Is it possible to have animation effects downloaded to hardware on the keyboard itself so it's nice and zippy?

P.S. If the answer is "it varies by vendor", what are some good vendors that run (customizable) RGB animation on keyboard hardware?